# disable select option based on a variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two select option in my code. First one selects the date and second one selects time. I want that If user selects today's date from select option 1, some time options from select option 2 should be disabled.

For ex. If user selects today's date(15), 6.00.00 time should be disabled. Again tomorrow if user will select 16, 6.00.00 time should be disabled. this should go on.

This is my code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

</head>
<body>
<select name="time"  id = "put_time">
<option value="Select Time">Select Time</option>
<option value="6.00.00" id = "t1">6.00.00</option>
<option value="6.30.00" id = "t2">6.30.00</option>
<option value="7.00.00" id = "t3">7.00.00</option>
<option value="7.30.00" id = "t4">7.30.00</option> 
</select>
<select name="date" id = "put_date">
<option value="Select date" >Select Date</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<script>
var today = new Date();
if(document.getElementById('put_date') == today.getDate())
{
document.getElementById("t1").disabled = true;
}
else{ 
document.getElementById("t1").disabled = false;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am not getting desired result. Someone please guide me how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementById('put_date')` returns a reference to the `select` element, not the value of its currently-selected option.

Comment: so what should I try to get the value of selected option? $('select[name=date]').val() is not working either.

Comment: Yes, that will work. If it's not, you're running it before the DOM has loaded or there's something else we can't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('put_date') == today.getDate()` is not a valid statement, you should compare the `value` of the element (`document.getElementById('put_date').value`). I also invoke the function on change, because on init the value of the second `select` is empty (not really empty, it's equal to `"Select date"`):

```js
function onChange() {
  var today = new Date();
  if (document.getElementById('put_date').value == today.getDate()) {
    document.getElementById("t1").disabled = true;
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("t1").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="time"  id = "put_time">
  <option value="Select Time">Select Time</option>
  <option value="6.00.00" id = "t1">6.00.00</option>
  <option value="6.30.00" id = "t2">6.30.00</option>
  <option value="7.00.00" id = "t3">7.00.00</option>
  <option value="7.30.00" id = "t4">7.30.00</option> 
</select>
<select name="date" id = "put_date" onchange="onChange()">
  <option value="Select date">Select Date</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution. it is quite similar to my code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @J.Doe, you're welcome, and yes, it's very similar to the provided code, you just forgot to get `value`. And notice, that the function should be invoked on every `select` change, it's important.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#put_date').change(function(){
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getDate();
      if($(this).val() == n){
        $('#t1').prop('disabled',true);
      }
  })
})
```